# SurveyMonkey. Creating my own front-end

Tags: surveymonkey

Can I create a SurveyMonkey survey, then build the survey's front-end on our intranet, but have the form post to the SurveyMonkey? This will allow me to use their result page and reports, while allowing me to design the page using internal video clips to vote on our intranet for a small user base of 225 users.

Comment: Their api would be a good place to start. https://developer.surveymonkey.com/‎

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no ability to post data with the Survey Monkey API. So far, you can only get data: [link](https://developer.surveymonkey.com/).

One option may be to use **embed** which allows you to embed a survey into your website: [link](http://help.surveymonkey.com/articles/en_US/kb/How-do-I-embed-a-survey-or-have-it-open-in-a-popup-window-on-my-site#part2).

Answer (score 1):

To add to the answer by philshem, you can embed videos from your intranet in your survey. As long as respondents have access to the video source, you should be able to get exactly what you're looking for. The link on SurveyMonkey's docs site about embedding media is http://help.surveymonkey.com/articles/en_US/kb/How-do-I-add-a-video-or-sound-clip-to-my-survey

The short answer is that you need to have HTML enabled for the survey and use an iFrame to embed the content.

Comment: In our case, we'd like to have custom user-based text for the questions but with standard answers (i.e, rankings). For example, I thought perhaps we could have multiple surveys embedded, each with single questions, but the embedded survey monkey javascript has too much footer text and also after each survey is completed, a Thank You message is presented.

Comment: If you're generating custom text for each user, you could either include it inside the iframe for your video source or create a separate element with the custom text embedded separately. Then, for the SurveyMonkey question, the text could be something very generic like "What is your rating?".

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful. In my case I want to create multiple single-question surveys that are in series embedded into my HTML. The problem is that it doesn't look nice at the end of each question to have "Thank you for taking the survey! Powered by Survey Monkey. Learn more" Is it possible to remove that message when the survey is completed?

Comment: I'm not sure if one of these options will work for you, but the options for what to do upon survey completion are documented here: http://help.surveymonkey.com/articles/en_US/kb/What-are-the-Survey-Completion-options